# I need to reset all my certificates, provisioning profiles, appIDs

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, app-id

I'm having troubles with my app because I can't make the notifications work, but in other apps I can. I think I have a very big problem with the certificates, wildcards, provisioning profiles.

The bundle id of my app is not like "com.myname.myapp", is just "my app". I don't know what to do the reset everything, certificates, provisioning profiles, appID, all certificates from my mac and start from scratch without breaking the app.

The app is already on the AppStore so I don't want to break anything.

¿What should I have to do?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is really because of certificates, wildcards, provisioning profiles problem. Problem might be with .pem, .cert for Pushes or with Push logic on device, did you asked permission, registered settings? All this worked while testing?

Comment: I think it's not problem of .pem and .cert files. I've created today a new app with push notifications, all from scratch, and worked. So I think I've got something wrong with the other app. That's why I wanna reset everything but I don't want to break anything. It's an app that already is on the store.

Comment: In the app where push notifications work fine I choose the provisioning profile I created and I got no problems. But with the other app I chose the prov. profile, just like the app that works, and when I'm building and installing in my iDevice I'm told "failed to get the task for process XXXXX" If a quit the prov. profile and select "automatic" it works, but no notifications.

Comment: Are you trying to use the same provisioning profile for the two different apps?  If so, that will not work.  I'm pretty certain that if you are trying to do push notifications, the provisioning profile must have a specific app ID (as opposed to using a wildcard app ID), and the app ID shouldn't be the same between two apps.